# SQL If Statment / select into in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I cannot understand why the following SQL procedure will not store on  my database and is reporting an error, I've been at it for ages and am totally puzzled.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_brand(IN inBrandName TEXT)
BEGIN

DECLARE brandexists INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT count(*) WHERE BrandName = inBrandName INTO brandexists;

IF brandexists = 1 THEN
select "exists";
ELSE
INSERT INTO tblBrand (BrandName) VALUES (inBrandName);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF;

END
```

The error  i'm getting is this:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE BrandName = inBrandName INTO brandexists; IF brandexists = 1 THEN sele' at line 6

any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a table where you select from .

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a table where you select from:

```
SELECT count(*)   WHERE BrandName = inBrandName INTO brandexists;
                ^---here (from some_table)
```

Comment: Oh my god.  Sometimes the simplest things really do shoot you down don't they? I'm embarrssed now.  Sorry for wasting your time